# component shows the error message and then renders the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I have this component that render a list of hotels information :

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {onSnapshot} from "firebase/firestore"
import {hotelCollection} from "../controller/controller";
import {HotelType} from "../types/hotel";
import Information from "../components/Information";

function Card() {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<HotelType[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => onSnapshot(hotelCollection, (snapshot) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setHotels(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                }
            })
        )
        setIsLoading(false);
    }), []);

    if (isLoading) return <div className="loading"/>;
    return (
        <div className={"card"}>
            <h2 className="title">All hotels</h2>
            {hotels && hotels.length ? (
                <div>
                    {
                        hotels?.map((hotel) => (
                            <Information key= {hotel.id} hotel={hotel}/>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            ): (
                <h2 className="no-hotels">There isn't any hotel, please add one.</h2>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

Everything works fine, except that when I enter the page, or access it through a route, it first displays

```
 <h2 className="no-hotels">There isn't any hotel, please add one.</h2>
```

Then it renders the component

I don't know why, anyone could help please?

Comment: Because `isLoading` is `false` and `hotels` is an empty array. What else would you expect? You are setting `isLoading` to `true` after data loads

Comment: On first render `hotels` state will be an empty array by default and then it will get populated. That's why you can see for a brief moment that there are no results. Since the `useEffect` runs only after the component gets mounted and has no dependencies, what you can do to avoid this is initialize the `isLoading` state with `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I received, instead of initialising "isLoading" to false, I set it to true,

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

I then removed this line :

```
 setIsLoading(true); // removed
```

And didn't touch the rest of the code.

It's solved.